# What was the occupation of Jacob given the occupations of his siblings?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Once upon a time, there lived a humble household of 5 children: Sam, Mary, George, Hannah and Jacob. They each grew up to have successful careers:

- Sam - Real Estate Agent
- Mary - Arcade Owner
- George - Tailor
- Hannah - News Reporter

Given the occupations of four of the siblings above, which of the following was the occupation of Jacob, and why?

- Jeweler
- Engineer
- Doctor
- Detective

Hint:

> They each took a path, that was calling their name,
>  and each got rerouted, to the jobs they chose to claim.

Hint 2:

> They played a game, to determine their future.
>  They typed in their names, into their computer.

Comment: Are unaanu cbegre or trbetr gnlybe, ice cold?

Comment: @Tacoタコス Didn't quite get your comment ^^" *(confused as to which parts are supposed to be encrypted)*. Can you wrap the whole sentence in rot13? Thanks!

Comment: rot13(V pna vqragvsl guerr bs gurfr crbcyr: Znel Qbjare, Trbetr Gnlybe, naq Unaanu Cbegre (nyy fhpprffshy crbcyr, V thrff), ohg qba'g xabj nalobql anzrq Wnpbo ;-;)

Comment: What Avi said is what I was getting at 

Comment: Does this puzzle need a "knowledge" tag ?

Comment: @Evargalo nope.

Comment: @Tacoタコス Well, it's pretty far off :)

Comment: Is it just about finding a pattern? If so, you could add the pattern tag.

Comment: @Nautilus It's an [enigmatic-puzzle] puzzle. I would like to know what makes this seem like a [pattern] puzzle, thanks.

Comment: It's a self-contained puzzle with nothing but a bunch of names and occupations, so every name must have been matched with a job following a rule.

Comment: does this require [lateral-thinking]?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget nope.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jacob was a

> Jeweler

The hints

> "path", "calling their name", "rerouted", "typed ... into their computer" mean to type the name as a url into the browser

Sam - Real Estate Agent

> sam.com reroutes to some real estate website

Mary - Arcade Owner

> mary.com is some sorta video game website

George - Tailor

> george.com reroutes to some clothing website

Hannah - News Reporter

> hannah.com is a news website

Jacob

> jacob.com reroutes to a jeweler website

Comment: "Knowledge: A puzzle whose solution relies on external sources such as tables, dictionaries, Wikipedia, or specifics that may not be common knowledge." I didn't know any of these brands (did anyone else?), and their ID's are accessible strictly as external sources (which, by the by, may quickly age the puzzle into defunctness). I think the knowledge tag is plenty applicable; OP's comments were only assuring me of exactly the wrong way to try to solve this puzzle.